# pre-compile jsp files happend exceptions

Tags: java, jsp, ant, jstl

I pre-compile some jsp files through ant task of jspc,but it built failed.

errers:
info.jsp(35,2) The attribute prefix fn does not correspond to any imported tag library

info.jsp line 35 :

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(requestScope.checkDetailInfoList) gt 1}">
```

ant task xml:

```
<jasper validateXml="false" uriroot="${basedir}/WebRoot" 
            webXmlFragment="${dir.WEB-INF}/generated_web.xml" 
            outputDir="${dir.WEB-INF}/src" />
```

How should I correct?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure the jsp file imports the `fn` namespace of the JSTL. You'll need a line that looks something like this in your jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Also, you'll need to make sure the JSTL jars (`jstl.jar` and `standard.jar`) are in your classpath when jasper tries to compile.

Comment: I add the fn "taglib" in the parent pages which included the info.jsp,
must declare the taglib in every pages?But the info.jsp pages  run Correctly on tomcat

Comment: @Diablo.Wu: You should include the taglib in each page that uses it.

Answer (score 2):

Asaph's comments are spot on.

There's one other bit to check:  The <fn> tag set was a later addition to the JSTL libraries.  Maybe you have an older version of jstl.jar and standard.jar that needs to be updated.